# MATLAB - Can't create symbolic variables through array loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, symbolic-math

I have this cell array

```
MatrixF = 

{3x1 cell}    {3x1 cell}

MatrixF{1}

ans = 

'f1'
'f2 '
'f3 '

MatrixF{2}

ans = 

'x1'
'x2 '
'x3 '
```

And I want to convert each item in the MatrixF array into a symbolic variable.  I thought that this loop would do that

```
 [a, b] = size(MatrixF);
 for i=1:b;
     [c,d] = size(MatrixF{i});
     for j=1:c;
        sym(MatrixF{i}{j});
     end;
 end;
```

But instead, the only output that I get is the variable ans, which is a 1x1 array.  Why is ans being declared as a sym instead of the individual variables thelselves, which are being called and accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ans` is being declared as a `sym` because the [`sym` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html) requires an explicit output argument to generate a Symbolic Variable.  This behavior is different from the [`syms` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/syms.html) that uses the semantics of [command form](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html) to poof a variable into existence.

Therefore, you can do the following:

```
 [a, b] = size(MatrixF);
 for i=1:b
     [c,d] = size(MatrixF{i});
     for j=1:c
        MatrixF{i}{j} = sym(MatrixF{i}{j});
     end
 end
```

Although, I'd suggest doing the much cleaner (and probably faster):

```
>> x = sym('x',[3,1])
x =
 x1
 x2
 x3

>> f = sym('f',[3,1])
f =
 f1
 f2
 f3
```